# awk: find minimum and maximum in column

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using **[awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)** to deal with a simple .dat file, which contains several lines of data and each line has 4 columns separated by a single space. 
I want to find the minimum and maximum of the first column.

The data file looks like this:

```
9 30 8.58939 167.759
9 38 1.3709 164.318
10 30 6.69505 169.529
10 31 7.05698 169.425
11 30 6.03872 169.095
11 31 5.5398 167.902
12 30 3.66257 168.689
12 31 9.6747 167.049
4 30 10.7602 169.611
4 31 8.25869 169.637
5 30 7.08504 170.212
5 31 11.5508 168.409
6 31 5.57599 168.903
6 32 6.37579 168.283
7 30 11.8416 168.538
7 31 -2.70843 167.116
8 30 47.1137 126.085
8 31 4.73017 169.496
```

The commands I used are as follows.

```
min=`awk 'BEGIN{a=1000}{if ($1<a) a=$1 fi} END{print a}' mydata.dat`
max=`awk 'BEGIN{a=   0}{if ($1>a) a=$1 fi} END{print a}' mydata.dat`
```

However, the output is **min=10** and **max=9**.

(The similar commands can return me the right minimum and maximum of the second column.)

Could someone tell me where I was wrong? Thank you!

Comment: The values are interpreted as strings, so the results are the min/max in lexicographic order.

Comment: I see, I need to cast string into int in awk. Thank you !

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Awk guesses the type.

String "10" is less than string "4" because character "1" comes before "4".
Force a type conversion, using addition of zero:

```
min=`awk 'BEGIN{a=1000}{if ($1<0+a) a=$1} END{print a}' mydata.dat`
max=`awk 'BEGIN{a=   0}{if ($1>0+a) a=$1} END{print a}' mydata.dat`
```

Comment: Also worth considering `awk 'NR==1{max = $1 + 0; next} {if ($1 > max) max = $1;} END {print max}'` which works reliably for different value ranges, and ensures that `max` is numeric in the first assignment.  If the file is of any size, calculating min and max in a single pass would help.

Comment: Also remove that spurious "fi" from the end of your if statements, e.g.:  `awk 'BEGIN{a=1000}{if ($1<0+a) a=$1} END{print a}' mydata.dat`.  In fact without that awk will guess the type correctly (although explicitly setting it per @Klaus's answer is better).

Comment: Right, your method is more flexible. If the data file has a header, your method allows to avoid the header and start with the first line of data.

Comment: If the dataset is non-negative numbers then this can be further simplified. No need to initialize `a` (so we can drop `BEGIN`) and not need to type coerse (`0+a`). This is because awk treat undefined variable in math expression as 0. So for max: `awk '{if($1>max){max=$1}} END{print a}'` will do.

Answer (score 11):

a non-awk answer:

```
cut -d" " -f1 file |
sort -n |
tee >(echo "min=$(head -1)") \
  > >(echo "max=$(tail -1)")
```

That tee command is <strike>perhaps a bit</strike> much too clever. tee duplicates its stdin stream to the files names as arguments, plus it streams the same data to stdout. I'm using process substitutions to filter the streams.

The same effect can be used (with less flourish) to extract the first and last lines of a stream of data:

```
cut -d" " -f1 file | sort -n | sed -n '1s/^/min=/p; $s/^/max=/p'
```

or

```
cut -d" " -f1 file | sort -n | { 
    read line
    echo "min=$line"
    while read line; do max=$line; done
    echo "max=$max"
}
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: Nice solution. But I'd also note that `sort` is a bit overkill for just finding min and max. My file had over 1 million lines and `sort` runs slower than other answers since it unnecessarily puts all values in order.

Answer (score 10):

Your problem was simply that in your script you had:

```
if ($1<a) a=$1 fi
```

and that final `fi` is not part of awk syntax so it is treated as a variable so `a=$1 fi` is string concatenation and so you are TELLING awk that `a` contains a string, not a number and hence the string comparison instead of numeric in the `$1<a`.

More importantly in general, never start with some guessed value for max/min, just use the first value read as the seed. Here's the correct way to write the script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { min = max = "NaN" }
{
    min = (NR==1 || $1<min ? $1 : min)
    max = (NR==1 || $1>max ? $1 : max)
}
END { print min, max }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
4 12

$ awk -f tst.awk /dev/null
NaN NaN

$ a=( $( awk -f tst.awk file ) )
$ echo "${a[0]}"
4
$ echo "${a[1]}"
12
```

If you don't like `NaN` pick whatever you'd prefer to print when the input file is empty.

Comment: I see. Your codes deepened my understanding. Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. If you are just starting to learn awk, I recommend the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: I haven't known that book before. I'll look it up. Thank you for the recommendation !

Comment: It's the only awk book that has all of the current awk information in it and it's presented well. It's also available online at http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html but IMHO the author deserves to get paid for all his work on the book and on GNU awk and it's a good reference to have in paper. Do not get "The AWK Programming Language" as it is out of date, and do not get "SED & AWK" as it's out of date too and you do not need a book to learn how to use sed for the things you should use it for so half the book is wasted pages.

Answer (score 9):

late but a shorter command and with more precision without initial assumption:

```sh
  awk '(NR==1){Min=$1;Max=$1};(NR>=2){if(Min>$1) Min=$1;if(Max<$1) Max=$1} END {printf "The Min is %d ,Max is %d",Min,Max}' FileName.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

**A very straightforward solution** (if it's not compulsory to use `awk`):

> Find Min --> `sort -n -r numbers.txt | tail -n1`
>
> Find Max --> `sort -n -r numbers.txt | head -n1`

You can use a combination of `sort`, `head`, `tail` to get the desired output as shown above.

(PS: In case if you want to extract the first column/any desired column you can use the `cut` command i.e. to extract the first column `cut -d " " -f 1 sample.dat`)

Comment: This suited my needs best, thank you for this! =)

Answer (score 0):

#minimum

```
cat your_data_file.dat | sort -nk3,3 | head -1 
                        #this fill find minumum of column 3
```

#maximun

```
cat your_data_file.dat | sort -nk3,3 | tail -1
                    #this will find maximum of column 3
```

#to find in column 2 , use -nk2,2

#assing to a variable and use

```
min_col=`cat your_data_file.dat | sort -nk3,3 | head -1 | awk '{print $3}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to use [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

check this out:

```
$ < mydata.dat datamash -t' ' min 1 max 1
```

output

```
4 12
```