# Minimum and maximum from columns

Tags: bash, awk

The purpose of the example is to create a file getting the minimum and maximum for 2 columns to generate an output with results.

input file

```
338043.75 2395256.25 36301 38676 1296
338056.25 2395256.25 36301 38677 1296
338068.75 2395256.25 36301 38678 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36301 38679 1296
338093.75 2395256.25 36301 38680 1296
338106.25 2395256.25 36301 38681 1296
338118.75 2395256.25 36301 38682 1296
338131.25 2395256.25 36301 38683 1296
338143.75 2395256.25 36301 38684 1296
338156.25 2395256.25 36301 38685 1296
338168.75 2395256.25 36301 38686 1296
338181.25 2395256.25 36301 38687 1296
338193.75 2395296.25 36301 38688 1296
338206.25 2395256.25 36301 38689 1296
```

using this code i got the desired output

```
x1=`sort -k1n file | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
x2=`sort -k1n file | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
y1=`sort -k2n file | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
y2=`sort -k2n file | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`

echo $x1","$y1 
echo $x2","$y1 
echo $x2","$y2 
echo $x1","$y2 
echo $x1","$y1
```

output desired

```
338043.75,2395256.25
338206.25,2395256.25
338206.25,2395296.25
338043.75,2395296.25
338043.75,2395256.25
```

Appreciate your inputs, I believe there is a better way to get the same output.

Comment: Not clear, please do mention all the requirements to get this output in your post.

Comment: The minimin and máximum for colums 1 and 2 is nedded in the desired output

Comment: I believe you need minimum and maximums on each line so based on that I given solution please check it once and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 OP mentions `getting the minimum and maximum for 2 columns` ... so it is not line based, rather column based.. and only for first two columns, rest are ignored

Comment: @Sundeep, thank you Sundeep I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing from Ed Morton's excellent answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29784278

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=","; x1=x2=y1=y2="NaN" }
       { x1 = (NR==1 || $1<x1 ? $1 : x1)
         x2 = (NR==1 || $1>x2 ? $1 : x2)
         y1 = (NR==1 || $2<y1 ? $2 : y1)
         y2 = (NR==1 || $2>y2 ? $2 : y2) }
       END { print x1,y1; print x2,y1; print x2,y2; print x1,y2; print x1,y1 }' ip.txt
338043.75,2395256.25
338206.25,2395256.25
338206.25,2395296.25
338043.75,2395296.25
338043.75,2395256.25
```

- `x1 = (NR==1 || $1<x1 ? $1 : x1)` this will give minimum number for first column. When `NR==1` (first line), `x` will get value of `$1`. For rest of the lines, `x1` will be updated if first column value is lesser than already saved value
- Similarly, using `>` comparison instead of `<` will give maximum number. Repeat for second column

Also, as mentioned by RavinderSingh13 in comments, `ORS` can also be used instead of calling `print` five times:

```
print x1,y1 ORS x2,y1 ORS x2,y2 ORS x1,y2 ORS x1,y1
```

Comment: Great code, kindly, can u explain how the code gets the minimum and maximum.

Comment: Great code, kindly, can u explain how the code gets the minimum and maximum.

Comment: Sundeep, IMHO you could use ORS to get new line in `awk` rather than having too many `print` in it too.

Comment: RavinderSingh13, kindly can you show how to use ORS to dont have many printt