# Find a maximum value from the second column and print value from the first column in awk or bash

Tags: bash, awk

I found a solution how to find a minimum and maximum value in awk [awk: find minimum and maximum in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783990/awk-find-minimum-and-maximum-in-column)
But instead of printing max value. I want to print the value from the first column in row in which is maximum value and print it to another file
Input:

```
 1.35571          65.2085
 1.36264          65.2541
 1.36957          65.3155
 1.37651          65.1064
```

Expected output

```
1.36957
```

Maybe I should use sort?

Comment: The question would be clearer to the next reader if you were to admit that you are not the owner of the columns. (I mean, _my_, _my_, _my_.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '
$2>max || max=="" {   # or $2>=max, depending on if you want first or last
    max=$2
    val=$1
}
END {
    print val
}' file
```

Output:

```
1.36957
```

Answer (score 2):

to "keep all lines' of first column with equal maximum values" in 2<sup>nd</sup> column:

```
awk '$2>max || NR==1 { max=$2; data=$1; next }
     $2==max{ data= data ORS $1 }
END{ print data }' infile
```